# Find unique values across all columns

Tags: pandas

I can check the number of unique values for a given column.

```
len(df.createdby.unique())
```

But is there a method to know the unique values acorss all columns?
I can run these 2 loops and get the results I need. But I am looking for a pythonic and elegant way of achieving this.

```
for i in df.columns:
    exec("print len(df.%s.unique())" % i)

for i in df.columns:
    print i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html), but it is not implemented for `DataFrame`, so need `apply`:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,7,7]})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  1  5  7
2  3  6  7

print (df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()))
A    2
B    3
C    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

From `0.20.0` onwards use `df.nunique()`

```
In [234]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 1, 1]})

In [235]: df.nunique()
Out[235]:
A    3
B    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `drop_duplicates` method

```
len(df.drop_duplicates())
```

Comment: This does not return the number of unique values per column.